# To return std::move (x) or not?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Are

```
std::vector<double> foo ()
{
    std::vector<double> t;
    ...

    return t;
}
```

and

```
std::vector<double> foo ()
{
    std::vector<double> t;
    ...

    return std::move (t);
}
```

equivalent ?

More precisely, is `return x` always equivalent to `return std::move (x)` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're not equivalent, and you should always use `return t;`.

The longer version is that if and only if a return statement is eligible for return value optimization, then the returnee binds to rvalue reference (or colloquially, "the `move` is implicit").

By spelling out `return std::move(t);`, however, you actually inhibit return value optimization!