# How to make a tuple of const references?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, tuples, tie

Say there are two functions:

```
void ff( const std::tuple<const int&> ) { }

template < typename TT >
void gg( const std::tuple<const TT&> ) { }
```

and calls to these functions:

```
int xx = 0;
ff( std::tie( xx ) ); // passes
gg( std::tie( xx ) ); // FAILS !!
```

GCC 4.7.2 fails to compile the last line and reports an error note like:

```
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   types ‘const TT’ and ‘int’ have incompatible cv-qualifiers
note:   ‘std::tuple<int&>’ is not derived from ‘std::tuple<const TT&>’
```

The first question is if this fits with the C++11 standard, and if it doesn't, then why?

Furthermore, to overcome this issue one needs to pass a tuple of const references to `gg` instead of passing a tuple of non-const references (which `std::tie` makes). This can be done by:

```
gg( std::tie( std::cref(x) ) );
```

however, an extra call to `std::cref` is kind of tedious, so it would be great to have something like `ctie` which would make a tuple of const references.

The second question is if there is a need to write `ctie` manually, and if yes, then is this the best way to do it?

```
template < typename... T >
std::tuple<const T&...> ctie( const T&... args )
{
    return std::tie( args... );
}
```

Comment: [Relevant, but not a dupe.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7867662/500104)

Comment: `return std::move(<Expression>);` is an anti-pattern - it's universally better to simply `return <Expression>;` In this particular case, `std::tie(args...)` is already an rvalue anyway. [See this answer for discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15981233/923854).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The first question is if this fits with the C++11 standard, and if it doesn't, then why?

This is expected behaviour. In the second case template argument deduction fails because there is no `T` so that `tuple<const T&>` becomes `tuple<int&>`.

In the first case it works because `tuple<int&>` is implicitly convertible to `tuple<const int&>`. This is a user-defined conversion and as such not considered during template argument deduction.

Your questions smells a bit like an X/Y problem. Consider posting the *real* question that made you look for a solution involving this kind of function template/tuple combination.

Your `ctie` function template looks fine. But keep in mind that things like

```
auto t = ctie(5);
```

will basically produce a dangling reference. So, you *might* want to restrict `ctie` to lvalues only.