# How to make a tuple of lvalue references from a tuple of values

Tags: c++

There are some questions which relate to this topic:

[How to make a tuple of const references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213374/how-to-make-a-tuple-of-const-references)

[std::make_tuple doesn't make references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867220/stdmake-tuple-doesnt-make-references/7867662#7867662)

But neither discusses how to make a tuple of lvalue references *from* a tuple of values.

Here is what I've got:

```
template <typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args&...> MakeTupleRef(const std::tuple<Args...>& tuple)
{
    return std::tie(tuple); // this fails because std::tie expects a list of arguments, not a tuple.
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, int> tup;
    std::tuple<int&, int&> tup2 = MakeTupleRef(tup); // the values of tup2 should refer to those in tup
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell `std::tie` is ideal here because it produces lvalue references, but it doesn't accept a tuple as an input. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Related/duplicate [Initialize tuple of references with reference to tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24918426)

Comment: `return std::tie( std::get<Is>(tuple)... )` would work probably, for an index sequence `Is`. But I wonder if there's a more direct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual `integer_sequence` trick:

```
template <typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
std::tuple<Args&...> MakeTupleRef(std::tuple<Args...>& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::tie(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
}


template <typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args&...> MakeTupleRef(std::tuple<Args...>& tuple)
{
    return MakeTupleRef(tuple, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
}
```

There's a simpler alternative if the types in the tuple are known to be unique:

```
template <typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args&...> MakeTupleRef(std::tuple<Args...>& tuple)
{
    return std::tie(std::get<Args>(tuple)...);
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this will only work on C++14, is that right?

Comment: @Arman C++14, or you can implement `integer_sequence` yourself. There must be half a dozen implementations on SO.

Comment: @arman `template<class T,T...>struct integer_sequence{};template<class T,T Max,T...ts>struct make_integer_sequence_t:make_integer_sequence_t<T,Max-1,Max-1,ts...>{};template<class T,T...ts>struct make_integer_sequence_t<T,0,ts...>{using type=integer_sequence<T,ts...>;};template<class T,T Max>using make_integer_sequence=typename make_integer_sequence_t<T,Max>::type;` should do it.